# UIRefreshControl not works in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uirefreshcontrol

I have ViewController which has TableView.

I added UIRefreshController to the table.

When I test it in iPhone it ok and works without any issue.

But when test it in iPad it not works.

You need to drag the table a lot to down to start refreshing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll need to help us a bit more with your explanation before we can begin to help (ie. maybe a description of your configuration or some code)

Comment: it seems like the table is too short  for the refresh progress indicator to complete the full progress for refreshing

Comment: @AlexanderMacLeod I add images, can you check it please? thanks.